# Can CMake be used to edit the PATH environment variable as part of project installations?

Tags: cmake, cpack

Is there some way to get CMake to edit the user's `PATH` environment variable to include the built binary(s) when doing an install

And how about for CPack outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You could use [`install(SCRIPT ...)` or `install(CODE ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#custom-installation-logic) to run a CMake script that uses the install target platform's available mechanisms to modify system environment variables, such as editing some file in the user's system environment config files (Which file you edit will depend on what such files exist on the user's platform. For example, for Deb and RPM, see [How to set an environment variable during package installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/490426/550426)), or editing the Windows registry (see [How can I modify a user’s PATH environment variable without logging out?](https://serverfault.com/q/33681/993961)).

Honestly, this sounds like a pain in the neck, and some users might not appreciate you making such changes to the system as part of your package's install procedure- at least not unless it's done very transparently.

I'd just leave it up to the user. After all, they're the one in control of where they install the built project to. And if they choose a conventional location, it'll likely install into somewhere covered by their `PATH` already (at least on UNIX systems).

If you're using the NSIS generator for CPack, see [`CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/cpack_gen/nsis.html#variable:CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH):

> Modify `PATH` toggle. If this is set to `ON`, then an extra page will appear in the installer that will allow the user to choose whether the program directory should be added to the system `PATH` variable.

Comment: so the basic answer is 'no', you have to do it yourself'. The convention for windows installs is that there is no common binary location (cf /usr/local/bin) so the PATH needs to be edited.

Comment: @pm100 not _exactly_: [Standard value of PATH variable Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/973153/1749748), [What is the default PATH environment variable setting on fresh install of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/124239/1749748). And again, for Windows, you can get what you want fairly simply with `CPACK_NSIS_MODIFY_PATH` if you use that CPack generator.

Comment: I assume you mean that I should install into system32. That is frowned upon, app binaries are expected to go into 'program files/xxx'

Comment: @pm100 I wasn't trying to imply that I think installing into those directories is a good idea. I was just mentioning that the `PATH` has a default value, which one could technically call a "common binary location".